# Error dialing loggregator server: websocket: bad handshake

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have cloudfoundry set up on AWS and followed tutorial from cloudfoundry docs.

I have 4 instancxes running right now

api/0

dea/0

data/0

core/0

I was able to push an applicatn sucessfully till yesterday, but when i tries on pushing yesterday push operation failed, and iam u nable to check logs due to following error.

Warning: error tailing logs

Error dialing loggregator server: websocket: bad handshake.

Please ask your Cloud Foundry Operator to check the platform configuration (loggregator endpoint is ws://loggregator.XX.XX.XX.XX.xip.io:80).

Iam not sure exactly where i need to check logs as well, i have used cf 146 as suggested by doc. I dont want to reset my complete set up.

Help in this issue would be very great.

Thanks & Regards,

Srilatha k.

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old version(146) of cf,please update it and retry pushing your app .

The latest release can be obtained here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

I will also suggest to enable traces "CF_TRACE=true cf logs myapp --recent" and provide o/p if still you get some error.

Comment: Thank you verymuch for your reply Diwesh, But  WRT cf command line tool iam using latest version cf v6. But cf release iam using older release cf146. So if i should deploy latest release iam not sure if the entire existing setup would get collapsed.

Comment: I want to deploy latest version as well, but iam afraid if i would loose all running instances and get new set of instances again, that i dont want.Please help me on this

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/vcap-dev/-VsQ9ptvlao/f3UiDPC2U40J may be this link can help you on upgradation without re-installation using BOSH

Comment: Is this the only option available, actually i have tried out monit stop all and monit start all in  all instances, still iam facing the issue.

Comment: You could also try to downgrade your CF cli to a version before 6.x. But I am afraid that upgrading is your best bet. Your instances should continue to run fine, if you have more than one DEA. Your instances will be moved from one DEA to another DEA, before the first one is shut down. BTW, v146 is so old (Oct 2013), that I have a hard time going through all the changes, to see what might trigger the bad handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Try out these things:-
1.) Try to simply restart of traffic controller and check if this solves the issue.

2.) Loggregator_consumer can be found @ https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator_consumer/blob/master/consumer.go.

3.) I also found from this Blog - https://blog.starkandwayne.com/2014/10/30/fixing-loggregator-problems-one-problem-at-a-time/ , that the issue would be fixed in v192. So please check in that version.

Steps to use the latest release can be found @ http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/common/cf-release.html

Looks like you dont want to upgrade, but without upgrade you may not be able to get the fix.
I am afraid could not find any other solution. You would need to upgrade cf to solve the issue.

As per the comments, in case the link breaks - Giving the information below-
CF-Release is the BOSH release repository for Cloud Foundry. Use this with a custom manifest for your environment to deploy Cloud Foundry.

This topic describes how you can create a Cloud Foundry release ready to deploy to your environment after bootstrapping BOSH.

Note: These instructions are for v170 release of Cloud Foundry. We strongly recommend using the highest final version tag of cf-release, though this may require that you modify the deployment manifest.
Clone CF-Release

Create a folder for your clone of the CF-Release repository and clone the repo from Github:

`$ mkdir -p ~/bosh-workspace/releases`
`$ cd ~/bosh-workspace/releases`
`$ git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release.git`
`$ cd cf-release`

Upload the Release

Releases of Cloud Foundry are published regularly. Use bosh upload release RELEASE-NAME to upload a release to your BOSH deployment. Replace RELEASE-NAME with the version of the cf-release YAML file of your choice. We recommend you use the highest final version tag of cf-release.

Run the following command to upload a release .yml file:

$ bosh upload release releases/cf-170.yml

### Copying packages

rootfs_lucid64 (1)            FOUND LOCAL
...

### Copying jobs

saml_login (4)                FOUND LOCAL
...

### Building tarball

Generated /tmp/d20130829-912-fq3kkd/d20130829-912-1vco0hv/release.tgz
Release size: 1.0G
...
Release uploaded

Run the following command to check that you have successfully added the release:

$ bosh releases

+------+----------+-------------+
| Name | Versions | Commit Hash |
+------+----------+-------------+
| cf   | 170      | 121623ca    |
+------+----------+-------------+

You can now deploy a release using a deployment manifest file.

Comment: Iam not sure if this is the correct workaround, but i have changed cf command line tool to 5.4.7, then this loggregator issue got solved, as iam using older verion of cf deployment older version of command line tool worked, iam not sure

Comment: @user3282197 could you please accept an answer so this can be closed out?